# "There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate" when doing pip install on a local artifactory repository

Tags: ssl, pip, artifactory

I could use some guidance on what needs to be put in place for resolving this SSL issue to an  artifactory server when running
`pip install`.  Is this "self signed certificate" supposed to be replaced by a specific one provided by that server?

```
Could not fetch URL [our.artifactory.server.name]/simple/hercl/: 
There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool
   (host='[our.artifactory.server.name]', port=443): 
Max retries exceeded with url: 
    /api/pypi/our.artifactory.server.name-local/simple/hercl/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, 
'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: 
self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1131)'))) - skipping
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credited to pip.pypa.io:

> Starting with v1.3, pip provides SSL certificate verification over
> HTTP, to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks against PyPI downloads.
> This does not use the system certificate store but instead uses a
> bundled CA certificate store. The default bundled CA certificate store
> certificate store may be overridden by using --cert option or by using
> PIP_CERT, REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE, or CURL_CA_BUNDLE environment variables.

In regards to the SSL issue, it depends whether you insist on SSL enforcement, if not, you may use an existing flag to ignore this by appending --trusted-host <server_name> ,in the example below: --trusted-host artifactory.

Some suggestions raised to overcome this issue are suggested here as well: [pip install fails with "connection error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:598)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi)

Do note, prior to using artifactory as a caching/proxy server for Pypi packages, you should configure the pip.conf and .pypirc files according to the SetMeUp instructions: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/PyPI+Repositories#PyPIRepositories-ResolvingfromArtifactoryUsingpip

For example:

pip.conf:

```
[global]
index-url = http://artifactory:8081/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-virtual/simple
```

.pypirc:

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
    virtual
    local
    remote
    devpi

[virtual]
repository: http://artifactory:8081/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-virtual
username: admin
password: ***

[local]
repository: http://artifactory:8081/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-local
username: admin
password: ***

[remote]
repository: http://artifactory:8081/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-org-remote
username: admin
password: ***

[devpi]
repository: http://localhost:3141/admin/dev
username: admin
password: ***
```